# Python: using .split() on an external text file

Tags: python, split

```
with open('books2.txt', 'rt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
for line in data:
    if 'Fiction' in line:
        line.split(' ,')
        print(line)
```

The above is my current code and the output is as following

```
The Great Gatsby, Fiction, Fitz Gerald,11/11/2021,0
```

How would i be able to split each line via the comma and print each split onto a new line?:

```
The Great Gatsby
Fiction
Fitz Gerald
etc
```

Comment: Replace without split? `print(line.replace(', ', '\n'))` But will there be titles with commas? Maybe use a csv parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split by "," and then remove white space from the splits. Join them with a "\n".

```
print("\n".join([ s.strip() for s in string.split(",")]))
```

output:

```
The Great Gatsby
Fiction
Fitz Gerald
11/11/2021
0
```